# Vuejs Vuex state overrides outside store without mutation or direct access to state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, mutation

State of Vuex overrides in the map()

Expecting beahavior - `count` always 1 when click to the Trigger button

Current behavior is  `count`  is encreasing each time  when click to the Trigger button
and if we take a look on a console log we can see that `getter` returns mutated state

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        stuff: [{
            count: 0
        }]
    },
    mutations: {},
    getters: {
        stuff: s => s.stuff,
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    store,
    data() {
        return {
            res: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        trigger() {
            const stuff = this.$store.getters.stuff
            console.log(stuff)
            const res = stuff.map(p => {
                p.count += 1
                return {
                    ...p
                }
            })
            this.res = res
        }
    },
})
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.6.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>
 <div id="vue">
  <div>
   <button @click=trigger()>Trigger</button>
   <pre>{{res}}</pre>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. Vuex is just a library inside JS virtual machine - the rules of JS applies...

[Value vs. Reference](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

1. `const stuff = this.$store.getters.stuff` - `stuff` is now a reference to an existing object (array in this case)
2. `stuff.map()` iterates the array passing each item as `p` parameter. If the `p` is an Object, `p` is the reference to an object inside Vuex - if you modify it, you are modifying the object inside the Vuex store

This is bad and to be sure and safe, you can set Vuex to throw an error anytime data inside Vuex are [modified without using mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html#development-vs-production)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```